# How to Get value from ini file with Python for selenium test?

Tags: python, selenium

After java i'm trying to create a simple login test with selenium using python.
So in my project i have created `test.ini` which contains:
[login]
username = tester@myapp.com

my python test file is:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import unittest, time, re
from web import*

class Login(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C://Selenium-driver//chromedriver.exe")
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "http://myapp.com/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_x(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/")
        timestr = time.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')
        time.sleep(30)

    try:
        from configparser import ConfigParser
    except ImportError:
        from ConfigParser import ConfigParser  # ver. < 3.0
             # instantiate
        config = ConfigParser()
             # parse existing file
        config.read('test.ini')
             # read values from a section
        string_val = config.get('login', 'username')    

        driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[@id='input'])[2]").click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[@id='input'])[2]").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[@id='input'])[2]").send_keys(string_val)

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException as e: return False
        return True

    def is_alert_present(self):
        try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        except NoAlertPresentException as e: return False
        return True

    def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
        try:
            alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
            alert_text = alert.text
            if self.accept_next_alert:
                alert.accept()
            else:
                alert.dismiss()
            return alert_text
        finally: self.accept_next_alert = True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

So when i run the python test, the username is never used from ini file.
the browser start with the url and then it closes by itself without errors.

Why i use ini file? because i wanted to create something like a `class repository` for web element and it did not work for me.
So after searching in google, it looks that i can use ini file to store all web element and then use in my test.

Can anyone help me, please.
Thank you

Comment: What are the exact contents of your `test.ini`, and where is it located relative to your other scripts? The one you posted in your question contains only a section header, not the `username` field you're trying to read from it.

Comment: the content of ini file is [login]
username = tester@myapp.com is located in the same folder of my python code.

Comment: it works now, thanks